# Load recylerView data at once (Stop lazy Loading)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading

I have a recyclerview with edittext  in which values are pre-populated but, recyclerView by default implements lazy loading so, I only get values of data which are visible, is there any way to stop this and load all the rows of recyclerView at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu don't.  That's the entire point of a recycler view-  to only display the items that are actually on screen.  If you don't want that behavior, you don't use a RecyclerView-  you use a scroll view with inflated items.  But you don't want to do that-  the size of your view hierarchy if N is anything non-trivial will take a TON of memory and a TON of time to inflate and scroll, your performance will be absolute shit.

Comment: I my case data is limited max 20 so i need to load at once and display grand total of all member.

Comment: Two things.  FIrst off-  if you need to display all at once, DO NOT USE RECYCLERVIEW, it isn't made for it.  Secondly-  loading the data and displaying it should be separate.  If your recycler view is loading data, you're doing it wrong.  Recycler view should be mapping already downloaded data to a view.

Comment: Is There Any Alternet Way to do this.

Comment: i no need to laod data , i have to choose from the list and display , Loading data is not i problem

Comment: You preload data.  You should never be loading data in the recycler view or adapter.  If you are, that is your problem.

Comment: Is there any other alternate way to achieve this functionality in android .

Comment: You don't need alternate functionality.  You need to use what's already there correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131393/discussion-between-rahul-chaube-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: could you suggest some code or link which help me to fix this .